# My Notes app accidentally got deleted from my iPhone 4s and I cannot locate it in the app list in iTunes when I synch. Any ideas?

Tags: iphone, applications

I accidentally deleted the Notes app and cannot find it (although when I do a spotlight search it does come up).  Any ideas how I restore it to my screen?  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like it's not deleted, but just off of the screen. I've had this happen to a few of my apps. What I always do to fix it is go to `Settings > General > Reset > Reset Home Screen Layout`. You'll get your Notes app back, but your Home Screen will be arranged into alphabetical order, and unless you're JailBroken, this is pretty much the only way to get it back without restoring.

Comment: Any advice on how to replicate this?  [My question...](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46111/how-do-i-hide-an-icon)

Comment: What if you got hundreds of apps?

Comment: @OliverDixon This was a bug in iOS 3, 4, and 5, and a lot has changed since then. If you're having a similar issue, I would suggest asking a new question.

Comment: Ah most questions/searches let to this. For anyone else having problems it's really easy. You can download any default app for free on the app store.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to delete it, as it is one of the built-in apps that you cannot remove.  You can, however, move it somewhere daft.  If you check in your app folders, and do the press-and-hold to move jiggle, it should show up somewhere, possibly on the mystery last screen.

You aren't close to the app limit by any chance are you?

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me today. The solution for me was simple.

Look carefully in each of your folders amoung your Apps.  It is possible that you moved it by mistake into one of them.

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried restoring your iPhone?

See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414 for the details on how to do this.