# Where has my Safari gone?

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

I have somehow managed to delete *Safari* from my *iPhone* and I can't get it back.  It's obviously still on my phone, because when I search for it, I can find, and use it.  Is there a remedy for this? Is it just a case of downloading the latest version of software?

Comment: If you could manage a screen shot (press and hold home and sleep, releasing both at the same time) showing how the screen looks when you find Safari - we might better know if it's in a folder, missing from the dock or only viewable from spotlight. You don't have the reputation to embed the image - but just link to any upload (flickr / imgur / whatever) and we will embed it for you. Great question BTW!

Comment: Found it! It had indeed just been moved out of place and found its way over to a neighboring page. Thanks everyone

Comment: Safari app will not be shown on your iPhone if Restrictions have been enabled for it. To check for and turn off Restrictions for the app (your Restrictions passcode will be required):

Go to: Settings > General > Restrictions - turn off the restriction for Safari.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like somehow the database that stores all the icon positions got in a jam and needs to be flushed.

You will lose all organization (but no actual data) if you choose to reset the home screen layout. This allows the springboard process to re-establish one icon for each app installed.

```
Settings > General > Reset > Reset Home Screen Layout
```

Check out this answer - its for another app icon, but the scenario is really the same.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/46108/9495

Comment: Cheers Mike  :-)