# I accidentally deleted my "contacts" app on my iPhone. How do I get it back?

Tags: iphone, ios

I accidentally deleted my "contacts" App on my iPhone.  How can I get the app back?

Comment: You can't accidentally delete this app since it comes with the OS. Either you placed it in a folder, or the software is corrupt or there's more to the setup like a jailbreak. Have a look at our guide [ask] and perhaps list more of your setup or what you have tried to fix this. Perhaps you might restore the OS and load your backup data from iCloud to remedy things?

Answer (score 8):

Unless you have jailbroken your phone you can't delete the Contacts app. Most probably it's either in a folder or on a screen somewhere. To find it again

- press the Home button repeatedly until the search screen is shown
- Type "Contacts"
- Select Contacts app from search results

If you can't find it, you could always back up your phone (to save the current settings) and also take screen shots of the various screens you have set up. Then go to the settings app and **Reset the home screen layout**.

Worst case is you wait while you restore your backup if this doesn't return contacts to the first screen.

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46105/my-notes-app-accidentally-got-deleted-from-my-iphone-4s-and-i-cannot-locate-it-i

Answer (score 3):

Are restrictions on? You may have accidentally blocked the Contacts app and consequently it's disappears from the home screen.

The other thing is you could have moved it accidentally - use Spotlight search (scroll left until you get a search box) and type in 'Contacts'.

Hope I could help!